# Is it possible to set a minimum number of builds to retain in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I maintain a couple of GitHub projects which don't have a lot of commit activity, and use Azure Pipelines for CI. A build status badge is displayed in their readme page.

The issue is that by default all builds are cleaned up after 30 days, and the badge then wrongly shows a *"never built"* status:
[image: status badge]

I'd like to change my settings so that the last few builds on the *master* branch are never deleted. Ideally, that should have been the default setting.

The [Build and release retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops) docs page suggests that there is a *"minimum number of builds"* retention setting somewhere, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Not in the organization settings, and neither in the project settings.

- The `_admin/_buildQueue` URL mentioned in the docs redirects to the *Parallel jobs* settings page which is unrelated to retention policy.
- The `_settings/settings` page at the project level does not have a *minimum number of builds* setting.
- The article has [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O3Dy.png) which shows the setting I need but I don't see a *Retention* tab anywhere in the build pipeline settings.

As a workaround, I've set the *"Days to keep runs"* setting to the maximum value for now, but what I'd really like is to set a small number of latest builds to retain instead. Is there a way to do that or has this option vanished?

Comment: Hi, does your puzzle solved by Josh's answer? Feel free to let us know the latest status.

Comment: @Merlin Hi, I've marked the question as solved since no other answer came up. I'd have preferred an option which would not require to use a release pipeline but I guess there's no better way. The documentation page is still outdated though, but there's a GitHub issue for that.

Comment: Yes, the doc about retention is too poor to get correctly guide. If you don't mind, you can raise a feedback on [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21)   to suggest Product Group notice on this outdated issue. Thanks in advance to help build our document:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

I haven't tested this explicitly in my sandbox org, but I am seeing it in our live org so I think I'm right.

Retaining a minimum number of **Build Artifacts** is inherited by the **Release Pipeline Retention Policy**

> Retain associated artifacts

This checkbox option is available on an individual stage for a pipeline, or in the default retention policy.

**Pipeline specific policy**
[image]

**Default retention policy**
[image]

### Original Answer:

This functionality changed since the [Sprint 150](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-151-update#azure-pipelines-app-for-microsoft-teams) update on April 8. This release was heavy on the Pipelines Areas and a lot of things changed.

### It seems the documentation is wrong (or unclear)

There should be a GitHub issue logged with that documentation page, as it is now out-of-data for what it says about build artifacts.

### Work around

Create a schedule trigger inside the threshold of the retention policy for those builds that don't turn over very often to make sure that you have a run and artifact for your badge to point to.

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed this feature in the release pipelines, but it basically means I need to create a release pipeline I don't necessarily need, although it may prove useful for pushing NuGet packages. BTW several issues are logged for that docs page.

Comment: Yep, I went and looked at the page just after I wrote my first answer and saw that too. It looks like it needs some attention if just for clarity.